# mySQL max() not returning max result

Tags: mysql

I have trouble trying to retrieve max courseid

Data:

```
coursename    courseid    
----------    --------
0001_Course   JAS9997
0002_Course   JAS9998
0003_Course   JAS9999
0004_Course   JAS10000
```

Query:

```
SELECT max(courseid) FROM tblcourse WHERE courseid LIKE '%JAS%'
```

The LIKE is to narrow down to courseid that begin with JAS.

The query only return JAS9999 as the max result but the max courseid is JAS10000. Am I missing something?

Comment: Courses that ___begin___ with `JAS` should be LIKE `'JAS%'`... courses that ___contain___ `JAS` would be LIKE `'%JAS%'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can't do `MAX` on numbers embedded in text like this. It makes alphabetical ordering and so JAS9 goes after JAS1. You will have to do max on a substring:

```
MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(courseid FROM 4) AS UNSIGNED))
```

Comment: it will still be a string though ... should be able to cast it by adding 0 i.e. MAX(SUBSTRING(courseid FROM 4)+0)

Comment: If the course id's aren't that predictable in format you can always load everything into a php array and do a natsort.

Comment: And yes, doing lots of substrings like this is a bad idea. Better to split courses in prefix and number if this is a crucial query.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of pure sql solutions where provided that should work on the assumption that all of the courses are formated with a three character prefix followed by numbers. I though I would throw in with a php solution.

First get all of the courses that match your like clause in an array.

```
 $matching = array();
 while ($matching[] = $query->fetchNext()){}
```

Then

```
natsort($matching);
$last = end($matching);
```

Last will contain the last JAS10000 in your case

Comment: And if there is 10 billion entries? You suggest copying all that data into RAM? For EVERY concurrent run of the script?

Comment: @maximkumpan I don't recall saying that, I was just illustrating that the second there is a course name QAMS0015 all of the other solution fall down, and that this may be a viable alternative.

Comment: Not sure this is necessary. Not in this case at least. Slow and right is good, but fast and right is better. And if you're working with large datasets and limited memory, this becomes slow and wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(courseid,4) AS UNSIGNED)) 
FROM tblcourse 
WHERE courseid LIKE '%JAS%'
```